# Is there a control out there that combines type ahead/auto suggest functionality along with a multi-select? B

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

Basically, I'm trying to type for something (say 'United' in a country field).  I would expect the auto suggest feature to suggest 'United States of America' and 'United Kingdom' for example.  On top of this, I would like to select both 'United States of America' and 'United Kingdom' by clicking on a link or button available directly on the narrowed down searh result (next to 'United States of America' and 'United Kingdom').  Please let me know if this is possible and if there is an existing example out there?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to look at the control vendor's sites. I know, for example, that Telerik has an AJAX suite that includes a multiple select combo box, with auto fill capabilities. I am not sure it fits precisely what you would like to do, however. Take a look at it:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx

Other component vendors:

```
http://www.devexpress.com
http://www.componentone.com
http://www.componentart.com
http://www.syncfusion.com
```

I am sure others can name a few more.

Comment: What I'm looking for is slightly different.  I've seen examples where you have combox box with auto fill capabilities but none of these lets you select more than one value.  I've definitely seen this implemented before but can't seem to locate it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Telerik does have a multiple select, but it is aimed more at the email type of selection and provides a comma separated list. But you could use something like this to feed your app. Admitedly, it is not a collection, which would be optimal.